# Sort by day of the year from today and looping round to yesterday

Tags: mysql

I have a database table `dates` with columns in the following format:

```
 -------------------------
| id | name | day | month |
 -------------------------
|  1 | matt |   7 |     3 |
|  2 | john |   2 |     1 |
|  3 | lily |  24 |    11 |
 -------------------------
```

Pulling data out sorted by month and then day is easy, but how can I get **all** the data out starting from today's date?

Standard SQL: `SELECT * FROM dates ORDER BY month ASC, day ASC`

I assume I need to use `CURDATE()` in some way.

For instance, today is April 17, so I would like the data returned like so:

```
 -------------------------
|  3 | lily |  24 |    11 |
|  2 | john |   2 |     1 |
|  1 | matt |   7 |     3 |
 -------------------------
```

As November 24 is the next date from today, then January 2, then March 7.

Comment: Looks like someone is too lazy to remember friends' birthday and wants to know the next ones :)

Comment: Exactly that. To be honest I'm learning Linux cron jobs, and thought a weekly email letting me know upcoming important dates would be the best thing to do, but I wanted a UI as well to view/edit them.

Comment: Being lazy is a fair reason to write programs and design DB

Comment: do you have any full date column?

Comment: I don't, no, as the year is not stored. Would it be better to store as 0000-03-07 in a full date field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

It's the union of 2 sub queries.

```
SELECT 
  rslt.id,
  rslt.name,
  rslt.day,
  rslt.month 
FROM
  (
    (SELECT 
      a.*,
      DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m-%d') AS cdate,
      CONCAT(
        LPAD(`month`, 2, 0),
        '-',
        LPAD(`day`, 2, 0)
      ) AS bday,
      1 AS rank 
    FROM
      `dates` AS a 
    HAVING cdate <= bday 
    ORDER BY bday ASC) 
    UNION
    (SELECT 
      b.*,
      DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m-%d') AS cdate,
      CONCAT(
        LPAD(`month`, 2, 0),
        '-',
        LPAD(`day`, 2, 0)
      ) AS bday,
      2 AS rank 
    FROM
      `dates` AS b 
    HAVING cdate > bday 
    ORDER BY bday ASC)
  ) AS rslt 
ORDER BY rank ASC,
  bday ASC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should help you get rid of your problem

```
(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d') cur_day, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m') cur_month,`day`, `month`, 'current_year' title
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING cur_day  >= DAY AND cur_month >= month
    ORDER BY `month` ASC, `day` ASC
)
UNION 
(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d') cur_day, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m') cur_month,`day`, `month`, , 'next_year' title 
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING cur_day < day and cur_month < month
    ORDER BY `month` ASC, `day` ASC
)
```

First I am getting all the rows from current year i.e. upcoming dates.
Second I am getting all the rows which are already passed and will come in next year.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM dates where day >= DAY(CURDATE()) ORDER BY month ASC, day ASC
```